# cURL: which information is needed to get access token to login to a website?

Tags: authentication, curl, https, oauth, http-headers

after successfully getting past the login page using curl in Linux (bash) with two sites that use information from the HTML-form field to accomplish this, I now also want to login to another site with my credentials that is a bit more tricky. I'm new to this and it seems that it works with OAuth so I need an access token first. With my two successfull attempts it was necessary to extract a CSRF token from the HTML code so as to prove I'm not a malicious bot. But now it's completely different and the server thinks I'm a bot (see error messages below).

Can somebody please confirm whether these are the only steps involved for logging in to an OAuth protected site:

1. a POST request to the server that generates the token (https://name_of_site/api/v1/auth/token)
2. a GET request to a password-protected part of the website using the access token from step 1

When I try step 1, I get error messages as shown below*. I inspected the website before logging in and afterwards with a browser and copied everything as cURL (bash). In the header fields of the token request I can find two more fields that look like they provide dynamic information:

- **x-trace-request-id**
- **x-recaptcha-v3**

I did some research and found that the request ID stays the same for some interactions that go to and from a server to facilitate identification of the client(?).
And concerning the recaptcha, I know what a recaptcha is, but I did not have to solve any captchas when accessing the site with a browser. So I'm quite unsure about these bits of information.
I strongly assume that I need to send one or both of these headers in the first step to actually get an acess token. **But how could I get valid values for these parameters with cURL?**
Any help is aprreciated! Please point me in the right direction. I can provide more information if needed, of course.

- `{"status":"ERROR","statusCode":400,"data":{"message":"Request failed with status code 400","error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid credential","bot-detection-error":"MissingAdditionalAuthToken"}}`

  This is the error I get when I do not provide x-trace-request-id and x-recaptcha-v3
  `{"status":"ERROR","statusCode":400,"data":{"message":"Request failed with status code 400","error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid credential","bot-detection-error":"InvalidCaptchaV3Token"}}`
  This is the error I get when I simply use the values as copied from the old request when I used the browser